# Does ISS perform any commercial operations?

Tags: iss

Other than accepting space tourists, that is.

I mean, does the ISS perform any commissioned experiments for private-owned entities, manufacture products that require space conditions, produce commercially sold media, or otherwise "earn money"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, commercial experiments happen on the ISS, but no, at least space agencies do not turn an explicit profit in business terms out of them. If you, as a company, want to run an experiment on-board the ISS, it is best to talk to your "local" space agency. Most of the stuff is done in cooperation between agencies and companies (and universities) anyway. Besides, research is intended to advance humankind and therefore your knowledge, so you can turn a profit out of it for sure.